# Needed clarifications for NSFetchedResultsController and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, synchronization, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Within SO there are a lot of questions/replies about `NSFetchedResultsController` and delegate. Sometimes the delegate fires, sometimes not. And since Core Data is quite complex argument is quite difficult to understand what is going on without spending a lot of time on it. In addition, the documentations says that there are several problems but it does not list them.

> There are several known issues and behavior changes
>   with NSFetchedResultsController on various releases of iOS.

Hence, I need some clarifications about the behavior of such a class. In particular, from the documentation there is written the following:

> A controller thus effectively has three modes of operation, determined
>   by whether it has a delegate and whether the cache file name is set.
>
> **No tracking:** the delegate is set to nil. The controller simply
>   provides access to the data as it was when the fetch was executed.
>
> **Memory-only tracking:** the delegate is non-nil and the file cache name
>   is set to nil. The controller monitors objects in its result set and
>   updates section and ordering information in response to relevant
>   changes.
>
> **Full persistent tracking:** the delegate and the file cache name are
>   non-nil. The controller monitors objects in its result set and updates
>   section and ordering information in response to relevant changes. The
>   controller maintains a persistent cache of the results of its
>   computation.

I'm developing a quite complex app and I'm taking advantage of `NSFetchedResultsController` to retrieve data from a store and display them in a table.
Displayed managed objects have a `syncStatus` boolean variable to verify if they have been synced with an external service or not. `syncStatus` variable is not displayed in a cell, different info are displayed (e.g. text values). In other words, `syncStatus` is not fired as fault.

In the table, by means of `NSFetchedResultsController`, I display the only elements that are not synced (the bool value is set to `NO`).

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController
{
    if(_fetchedResultsController)
        return _fetchedResultsController;

    NSManagedObjectContext* mainContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LocalEntity" inManagedObjectContext:mainContext]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"syncStatus == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

    // sort descriptor here...

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:mainContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

The user can select the elements she/he wants to sync and a background thread sends the selected elements to the service and, for those, it also changes the `syncStatus` variable to `YES`.

When the operation is finished, since I set the `NSFecthedResultsControllerDelegate` and I register for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` (**I also merge in the main thread the changes through the notification. I'm able to see that the notification contains objects with the correct change**), I expect the table is updated (the objects with `syncStatus` set to `YES` would be not displayed).

Said this, the question is the following.

Based on doc, since I use the **Memory-only tracking** option, does the missing update is due to the fact `isSyncStatus` is not loaded on memory but it remains a fault?

Could you suggest me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

**P.S.**

`NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods are implemented correctly. Doing the same only in main thread works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you implementing the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods to remove the cell?

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];    
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];    
            break;
    }    
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView endUpdates];    
}
```