# CoreData import not caught by NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My NSFetchedResultsController is not getting updates to newly imported objects.

1. On a background thread I create a NSManagedObjectContext that is not a child of my main context and add an observer so I can merge the changes.

   ```
   NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
   [localContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextDidSave:)
                                                name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
   …
   -(void) contextDidSave:(NSNotification*) notification
   {
       if(![notification.object isEqual:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]] && ![notification.object isEqual:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_rootSavingContext]])
       {
           NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
           NSLog(@"updated: %i, inserted: %i", [userInfo[@"updated"] count], [userInfo[@"inserted"] count]);
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                      {
                          [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
                      });
       }
   }
   ```
2. I create and object and sets its "visible" attribute to NO.
3. Save the context.
4. Update the objects "visible" attribute to YES.
5. Save the context.

   ```
   MyEntity *entity = [MyEntity insertInManagedObjectContext:localContext];
   entity.dateCreated = [NSDate date];

   if (![localContext save:&error]) {
       NSLog(@"%@", error);
   }

   [entity setVisibleValue:YES];

   if (![localContext save:&error]) {
       NSLog(@"%@", error);
   }
   ```

The `NSFetchedResultsController` has a fetchedRequest that filters on the "visible" attribute.

The updates are being received by contextDidSave:.

Sometimes the objects do make it though and get inserted by the `NSFetchedResultsController`. This makes me think that I am doing things correctly and I am looking at a CoreData bug. On the other hand I am not sure what exactly is going on in the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` method.

The code I am used to isolate the problem can be found at https://github.com/onato/CoreDataImportTest

Comment: Problably the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018068/nsfetchedresultscontroller-doesnt-call-controllerdidchangecontent-after-update.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3927811/215748

Comment: OK, so we can close this as a duplicate.