# NSFetchedResultsController remove row from UITableView after update relationships

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

This is how I setup `NEFetchedResultsController`:

```
private func setupOnceFetchedResultsController() {

    if fetchedResultsController == nil {
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()
        let fetchReguest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WLWishlist")
        let dateDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)

        fetchReguest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY users.identifier = %@", String(WLAppSettings.currentUser!.identifier) )
        fetchReguest.sortDescriptors = [dateDescriptor]
        fetchReguest.fetchLimit = 10
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchReguest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This is my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            print("--->>>REMOVED")
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }
    case .Move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let newIndexPath = newIndexPath where indexPath != newIndexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result when I scroll view up:

[image]

When I select last cell ("*My First List*"), I fetch another objects and assign them as a child of selected object (**WLWishlist**)

Once I select that cell, and then press back I have a result:

[image]

So there is no last cell, and `didChangeObject` method was called with changeType of `DELETE`.

In another controller I have a method to parse and save some objects:

```
if let itemsInfo = responseObject?["wishlist_items"] as? Array<NSDictionary> {

    MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ context in

            let wishlist2 = WLWishlist.findWishlistWithIdentifier(Int(wishlist.identifier), inContext: context)

            if page == 1 {
                wishlist2!.items = Set()
            }

            for itemInfo in itemsInfo {

                let item = WLItem.findOrUpdateItemWithDictionary(itemInfo, inContext: context)
                item.wishlist = wishlist2
            }

            print("-------------->>>before removing items")
            WLItem.removeOrphanedItemsInContext(context)
            print("-------------->>>after removing items")

            }, completion: { finished, error in
                print("-------------->>>saved items")
                completionBlock(error)
        })
    }
```

Pay attention for print logs.

The output on console is:

> 2015-09-03 15:28:49.825 Wishlist[94972:1987359] Created new private queue context: 
>   -------------->>>before removing items
>   -------------->>>after removing items
>   2015-09-03 15:28:49.836 Wishlist[94972:1987852] → Saving  on a background thread
>   2015-09-03 15:28:49.839 Wishlist[94972:1987856] → Saving  on a background thread
>   --->>>REMOVED
>   -------------->>>saved items

**Please, tell me, what is wrong?** Everything is because of this line:

```
item.wishlist = wishlist.
```

When I comment this out, it's fine.

Comment: Having same issue.. Any luck figuring it out?

Comment: Yes, I know what is the common problem. Can you ask a question, and then I answer it? Please attach some code to debug this. I am almost sure what may be wrong in your case. Send me a link to that question here.

Comment: In two words, what problem was in your case here?

Answer (score -1):

Removing keypath (with dot) from fetchResultsController fixed it for me. In my case it was as simple as changing groupBy value from "location.name" to "location"

EDITED
Turns out this affects objects that do not have sortBy value (those that trigger "A section returned nil value for section name key path" error), so changing the groupBy value to the one that is guaranteed to be available fixed my problem